# How can I use the Azure portal to position my App Service at a url which is not at the root of the domain?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure WebSite ... **MyApp**

This naturally places my application at http://MyApp.AzureWebSites.net

I also have a domain ... http://MyWebSite.com

I understand that I can upgrade my App Service Plan to one which includes Custom domain name support which will allow me to position my app at http://MyWebSite.Com/MyApp

What I would like to do is to position MyApp in a different location.

I'd like to be able to access it via http://MyWebSite.com/SomeOtherFolder/MyApp

For bonus points, I'd like to be able to access it via http://MyWebSite.com/SomeOtherFolder/SomeOtherAppName

So how can I use the Azure portal to specify the endpoint for my application?

Answer (score 2):

If you upload your site on a custom domain the default url is **MyWebSite.com**
For put other site in a diferent folder into the domain origin (**MyWebSite.Com/MyApp**), use **FileZilla** for update the files after create MyApp folder into **/site/wwwroot**:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/

And if create another folder into MyApp (http://MyWebSite.com/SomeOtherFolder/SomeOtherAppName) looks like (**/site/wwwroot/SomeOtherFolder/SomeOtherFolder** )